# Symfony Form Component. What are all available options as 3rd argument of FormBuilderInterface::add() method

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

How do I know what **all** options are available as 3rd argument of [`FormBuilderInterface::add()`](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilderInterface.html#method_add) in Symfony Form Component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type of form field you're adding. Full list of default fields is here https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#built-in-field-types and then all available options are listed in the documentation for each form field.

For example `TextType` has just a few basic ones https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html.

On the other hand `EntityType` has it's own extra options and then inherits all options from its parents https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html.